# Simple circuit breaker implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a basic [circuit breaker design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern) for my internal API calls. I would appreciate some criticism and feedback about my code. I am also planning to implement an interface off of the class once I am happy with it. As mentioned this circuit breaker design will be used for internal gRPC calls between my microservices. This was written in .NET Core 3.0.

I look forward to your feedback!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace CircuitBreaker
{
    public class CircuitBreaker
    {
        private Action _currentAction;

        private int _failureCount = 0;
        private readonly int _threshold = 0;
        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        private CircuitState State { get; set; }

        public enum CircuitState
        {
            Closed,
            Open,
            HalfOpen
        }

        public CircuitBreaker(int threshold, int timeOut)
        {
            State = CircuitState.Closed;
            _threshold = threshold;
            _timer = new Timer(timeOut);
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        }

        public void ExecuteAction(Action action)
        {
            _currentAction = action;
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException == null)
                    throw;
                if (State == CircuitState.HalfOpen)
                    Trip();
                else if (_failureCount < _threshold)
                {
                    _failureCount++;
                    Invoke();
                }
                else if(_failureCount >= _threshold)
                    Trip();
            }

            if(State == CircuitState.HalfOpen)
                Reset();

            if (_failureCount > 0)
                _failureCount = 0;
        }

        public void Trip()
        {
            if (State != CircuitState.Open)
                ChangeState(CircuitState.Open);

            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            ChangeState(CircuitState.Closed);

            _timer.Stop();
        }

        private void ChangeState(CircuitState callerCircuitState)
        {
            State = callerCircuitState;
        }

        private void Invoke()
        {
            ExecuteAction(_currentAction);
        }

        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (State == CircuitState.Open)
            {
                ChangeState(CircuitState.HalfOpen);

                _timer.Stop();

                Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out `Polly` on Nuget? if not, check it out, as it has already Circuit Breaker https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: I had a look at Polly, but would really like my own implementation to be reviewed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review.  Not too bad but I would suggest a few things.

`_failureCount` is only used in `ExecuteAction` so I would only define it locally to `ExecuteAction` and renamed it simply `failureCount`.

You may want to expose threshold publicly as a property since different instances could have differing thresholds.  Suggest:

```
public int Threshold { get; }
```

Consider having a `ToString()` override.

`CircuitState` enum is okay where its at, but if it were me, I usually define it external to the class.

You may consider having the `State` be gettable publicly.  Suggest:

```
public CircuitState State { get; private set; }
```

I see no reason for `Invoke()`.  Just call `ExecuteAction(_currentAction)` directly.

The constructor has a `timeout` parameter.  I would encourage clarity in the name with `millisecondsTimeout`.

And finally, the biggest issue I see is that you really should get into the practice of use `{ }` with `if`.  I know C++ was okay with this, and C# allows it, but here at CR we strongly discourage it because it could lead to nefarious hard-to-find bugs. There are lots of places where you would change this; here is but one example:

```
if (State != CircuitState.Open)
{
    ChangeState(CircuitState.Open);
}
```

Comment: You can't just move _failureCount to be a local variable. It needs to be in the class scope so it can count the number of failures over a set of ExecuteAction calls, otherwise it will never be greater than 1 due to the recursive (through Invoke) nature of ExectueAction.

You could, instead, move it to be a parameter of ExecuteAction with a default value of 0 and then pass it in the call that replaces Invoke if you want it to not be in the class scope.